# Приложение крашется под отладчиком - Microsoft C++ Exception (ext.code e06d7363)!

Tags: исключения, обратная-разработка

Хочу обратиться за помощью к реверсерам и дизассемблерщикам. При исследовании программ меня очень сильно донимает одна проблема: часто, при запуске исследуемой программы под отладчиком, выскакивает следующее исключение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После нажатия на ОК, обычно выбрасывает либо в ntdll.dll, либо в KernelBase.dll:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я продолжаю выполнение (F9) и нажимаю Yes (pass to app), то возможны три сценария развития событий:

1. программа продолжает работу, как ни в чём не бывало;
2. данное исключение выбрасывается снова, и снова, и снова, и... (после Detach from process крашется);
3. сразу крашется - процесс завершается с ошибкой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разумеется, если приложение запускается не под отладкой, то оно работает без всяких ошибок.

Я заметил, что подобные исключения чаще всего происходят тогда, когда в приложении вызывается форма открытия или сохранения файла.
Всё, что нашёл по данной ошибке, так это описание:

> The Windows 10 error ‘EXTERNAL EXCEPTION E06D7363’ occurs when a program tries to copy or move a locked file. It may be locked by Windows, your antivirus software or malware scanner, the error isn’t picky.

Из этого я могу предположить, что когда программа, работающая под отладчиком, пытается обратиться к системе для доступа к файлам и папкам, чтобы открыть или сохранить свой проект, система блокирует доступ и выбрасывает данное исключение.

Собственно, мой вопрос очевиден: как решить данную проблему? Как сделать так, чтобы программы можно было нормально запускать под отладчиком без всяких подобных экзепшнов?

Техническая информация: OS Windows 10, дизассемблер IDA PRO 7.0, выбранный отладчик Local Windows Debugger.

Comment: воспользоваться обычным отладчиком? многие защиты очень не любят, когда их запускают с под IDA или Olly и будут мешать.

Comment: Каким обычным отладчиком?

Comment: Visual studio, windbg. Хотя я лично предпочитаю статическую отладку - это когда не нужно запускать, а все на листике. Против этого защиты безсильны

Comment: Когда нет исходников (что естественно), а размер кода исследуемого модуля превышает 20 Мб, "отладка" на листке займёт годы жизни, которая у нас и так не слишком длинная))

Comment: в 99 процентов случаев нужное место все равно занимает несколько килобайт от силы

Comment: Скажу больше, в большинстве случаев нужное место может занимать всего несколько байт. Не в размере дело, а в том, что это место нужно отыскать среди десятков мегабайт всего остального кода! Без брейкпоинтов, отслеживания содержимого регистров/памяти и пр. приёмов динамического исследования такой поиск становится заведомо гиблым делом. Кроме того, нужное место может быть далеко не одно, и не в одном файле...

Answer (score 3):

На случай, если кто-то будет ещё искать (как я сам только что делал...) ответ на этот вопрос...
Да, решение может не сработать, но стоит попробовать в окне Exception Handing не просто нажать Yes (Pass to App), а предварительно зайти в пункт Change Exception Definition. По умолчанию там будет стоять следующая настройка:

[image: Настройки для исключений по умолчанию]

Для таких исключений я её меняю на вариант:

[image: Вариант пропуска исключения]

Аналогичные действия можно провести из меню Debugger > Debugger options... > Edit exceptions. Там приведён список всех обрабатываемых исключений, конкретно это:

[image: Изменение обработки исключений через меню]

После этого сообщения об исключениях если и есть, то они успешно улетают в лог, не прерывая работу отладчика.
Не встречал ситуации, где это бы не помогло, но может как раз тут - не тот случай.